# Prove that the derivative of the function f(x) = e^(-1/x^2) at x is 0

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be defined such that $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ when $x \neq 0$, and let $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$. How can I go about proving that $f'(0) = 0$?

I know that:

$f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$

But beyond this point I don't know what to do. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is written as :

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1/x}{e^{1/x^2}}  $

After that apply L'Hospital's rule and you should be able to work your way into $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}x} = 0$